# TTreeView: AlphaSort scrolls to selected node (like MakeVisible)

Tags: delphi, treeview, scroll

Good day to all!

I have some problem. When I call AlphaSort for parent node of selected node (selected node is not visible at the moment because I have scrolled down or up treeview), treeview scrolls to selected node (like call MakeVisible). How can I forbid treeview to ensure visible during sorting? I have tried to intercept TVM_ENSUREVISIBLE like this

```
type
  TTreeNode = class(ComCtrls.TTreeNode)
    protected
      procedure EnsureVisible(var Message: TMessage); message TVM_ENSUREVISIBLE;
  end;

type
  TTreeView = class(ComCtrls.TTreeView)
    protected
      procedure EnsureVisible(var Message: TMessage); message TVM_ENSUREVISIBLE;
  end;

...

{ TTreeView }

procedure TTreeView.EnsureVisible(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  ShowMessage('MakeVisibleFromTreeView');
end;

{ TTreeNode }

procedure TTreeNode.EnsureVisible(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  ShowMessage('MakeVisibleFromTreeNode');
end;
```

but there is no call of this message during scrolling in sorting. Only if I call MakeVisible manually.

Comment: That's the behaviour of the underlying control. And it's going to be quite difficult to come up with a fully general solution that makes sense for all scenarios.

Comment: @David, you can save the scrollbar position and restore it after the sorting is done while the window will be locked for updates during sorting process.

Comment: @TLama Yes. But then the result may be that the control is now showing a completely different part of the tree. For instance, if, before the sort, there is an expanded node with 1000 children, not visible, below the currently visible nodes. Then, after the sort, that expanded node moves higher up the tree, you can be left wondering how you got to this part of the tree.

Comment: @TLama, How can I lock TreeView for updates? I have tried to save and restore scrollbar position, but it is visible that scrollbar jumps to selected node and then return back.

Comment: @GaaraofDesert Do you understand my point? That restoring scroll bar position may give strange behaviour. I think you need to specify clearly what behaviour you want.

Comment: @David Heffernan, Yes, I understand it. And I wouldn't try this method if it was unnacceptable for me. Sorting could change position only for nodes, that had not children. So saving and restoring could be solution of my problem (but only if I could lock treeview to prevent jumping of scrollbar).

Comment: Would it not be confusing for the sort to change completely the nodes that were visible and place you into a part of the tree view that you could not see at all before you sorted? That's what will happen if you freeze the scroll bar.

Comment: @David Heffernan, I understand. No, there cannot be such situation. Sorting could change order of nodes only.

Comment: What if the nodes that you are sorting have children? If they don't have children then I have an easy solution for you.

Comment: @David Heffernan, Visibility and order of nodes with children are not changing in sorting. Is is some kind of contact list, where nodes with children are groups and subgroups (hierarchical structure of persons) and nodes without children are persons in this groups. Person can have states "Online", "Offline", "Away" etc and sorting orders persons in group due to this states. So there are not nodes with children and state both.

Comment: Can you confirm then that the all of the nodes that are being re-ordered do not have children?

Comment: @David Heffernan, Yes. If I have a way to lock TreeView, saving and restoring could be a solution of my problem. But I don't know how can I do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour that you observe is supplied by the underlying tree view control. There's probably not much that you can do to stop it happening. So, if you want to change the behaviour, you would need to work around this behaviour.

You do have to decide what behaviour you actually want though. Which nodes do you want to be visible when the sort is complete. @TLama suggests storing scroll bar position, sorting, and then restoring scroll bar position. But that could have quite surprising results. For a start, there's no guarantee that any of the nodes that were visible before you sorted would be visible after you sorted. And if the nodes that you are sorting have children, that could also compound the oddities.

However, you say in the comments that the nodes being sorted do not have children. In which case I think that what @TLama suggests will meet your needs. And there's a rather easy way to achieve it. You need to remember the index of the top item before the sort, and then, after the sort, set the top item to be the item with that index. Like this:

```
TreeView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
try
  TopIndex := TreeView1.TopItem.Index;
  TreeView1.AlphaSort; // or whatever you do to perform the sort 
  TreeView1.TopItem := TreeView1.Items[TopIndex];
finally
  TreeView1.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```